# Assigning a random number on the screen resolution limit to the label in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

My question is exactly this. For example, let's say we have a label that I call MoveY. Let me print a random number within the Y resolution limit of that monitor. Can I do this with randomized? Or is there another way? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: What you require is actually very easy, even with basic knowledge. However, you need to make an attempt, if it doesn't work in some way, post your code, with the exact problem. People here will undoubtedly help you.

Comment: Assign a random number : `Dim rnd As New Random()`
`MoveY.Text = rnd.Next(limit number).ToString()`